# Why is Baudelaire the last name of Beatrice Baudelaire II?

Tags: a-series-of-unfortunate-events

In the Netflix series, it is clear that Beatrice Baudelaire II's mother is Kit Snicket and father is Dewey Denouement. So why is her last name Baudelaire?

---

***Note**: In the books, it's hinted but less clear that her father might be Dewey Denouement. So given also that the Baudelaire siblings cared for her at least during her infancy, it's plausible that she takes the last name Baudelaire. But in the TV series, this seems a bit less plausible unless I missed something.*

Comment: https://snicket.fandom.com/wiki/Beatrice_Baudelaire_II

Answer (score 2):

Beatrice Baudelaire the second is adopted by Klaus, Violet, and Sunny. She takes on their last name since she isn't 100% sure who her real father is. It is very cryptic in the Netflix series and doesn't explain anything like the books do.

> *"Violet told me once that I saved her life, and Klaus claimed that without me he would have died in despair not long after the destruction of the Hotel Denouement. Even Sunny said that she could not have survived without me. But I don't have to tell you how brave and resourceful, how loyal and well-read those three people are. It is I who would have been lost without them.”*
>
> ~ [Beatrice Baudelaire II, The Beatrice Letters, BB to LS #5](https://snicket.fandom.com/wiki/Beatrice_Baudelaire_II#Netflix%20Series%20Divergent%20Canon)